# jQuery select first child three levels deep

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="s1>
 <div class="s2">
  <span class="span1">
    <span>text</span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

Currently I am selecting the most nested span with the following selectors:

```
$(".s1").find(">:first-child").find(">first:child").find(">:first-child")
```

Is there a more efficient way to select that inner span?

Edit: Div with class s1 is already cached, so I cant use $("selector").

Comment: You can't give that span a class?

Comment: $(".s1").children(":first").children(":first").children(":first") but it's not much better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it through span1 class,

```
$('.span1 span')
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. At the end I used s1.find(".span1 span");

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, something like this should work:

```
.s1 .s2 .span1 span:first-child
```

I'm not sure how specific you need the selector to be.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a class or Id and then try accessing it

```
 <span id="sp1" class="sp1">text</span>

$('#sp1')  or $('.sp1')
```

// Or

```
$('.span1 > span')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about efficiency the fastest is to define an id for the span:

```
<span id="spanX">text</span>
$('#spanX')
```

Because this selector maps directly to the cross-browser getElementById

If you cant touch the html for some reason the fastest way would be:

```
$('.span1 span:first')
```

Comment: jsPerf for this solution says its 73% less efficient than the proposed answer.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about the span:first, thanks for pointing it out. The test: http://jsperf.com/span-vs-span-first

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div.s1 > div:first-child > span:first-child > span:first-child')
```

Do you need anything more specific than that?